# CentOSにおけるカーネルバージョンの管理について

Tags: centos, kernel

**質問内容**

1. CentOSのカーネルについて、最新のカーネルバージョンが適用してあれば、過去のカーネルバージョンの修正が含まれると考えてよろしいのでしょうか？

yum updateするタイミング・周期により、適用されるバージョンが異なる環境A,環境Bができてしまいました。
　どちらも最新の「3.10.0-1160.45.1」★を適用しているのは同じです。
　Nesusのような脆弱性診断用のツールで診断すると環境Aは指摘はないのですが、
環境Bでカーネル脆弱性を指摘されるという差異が発生しました。

2. もし、過去のバージョンの修正が含まれないため、個別に各バージョンのカーネルを適用しなければならないとした場合、どういった方法がありますか？

□環境A

```
    $ yum list installed  | grep kernel
    kernel.x86_64                         3.10.0-327.36.3.el7             @updates
    kernel.x86_64                         3.10.0-1062.18.1.el7            @updates
    kernel.x86_64                         3.10.0-1127.el7                 @base
    kernel.x86_64                         3.10.0-1127.19.1.el7            @updates
★   kernel.x86_64                         3.10.0-1160.45.1.el7            @updates
    kernel-headers.x86_64                 3.10.0-1160.45.1.el7            @updates
    kernel-tools.x86_64                   3.10.0-1160.45.1.el7            @updates
    kernel-tools-libs.x86_64              3.10.0-1160.45.1.el7            @updates
    $ cat /etc/redhat-release
    CentOS Linux release 7.9.2009 (Core)
    $
    # yum history package-list kernel.x86_64
    読み込んだプラグイン:fastestmirror
    ID     | 操作           | Package
    -------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        54 | 削除           | kernel-3.10.0-327.4.5.el7.x86_64
        54 | インストール   | kernel-3.10.0-1160.45.1.el7.x86_64
        47 | 削除           | kernel-3.10.0-123.el7.x86_64                       EE
        47 | インストール   | kernel-3.10.0-1127.19.1.el7.x86_64                 EE
        42 | インストール   | kernel-3.10.0-1127.el7.x86_64                      ##
        34 | インストール   | kernel-3.10.0-1062.18.1.el7.x86_64                 ##
        29 | インストール   | kernel-3.10.0-327.36.3.el7.x86_64
         7 | インストール   | kernel-3.10.0-327.4.5.el7.x86_64                   EE
         1 | インストール   | kernel-3.10.0-123.el7.x86_64
    history package-list
```

□環境B

```
    $ yum list installed | grep kernel
    kernel.x86_64                        3.10.0-957.5.1.el7             @updates
    kernel.x86_64                        3.10.0-957.21.2.el7            @updates
    kernel.x86_64                        3.10.0-957.21.3.el7            @updates
    kernel.x86_64                        3.10.0-1160.42.2.el7           @updates
★   kernel.x86_64                        3.10.0-1160.45.1.el7           @updates
    kernel-devel.x86_64                  3.10.0-957.5.1.el7             @updates
    kernel-devel.x86_64                  3.10.0-957.21.2.el7            @updates
    kernel-devel.x86_64                  3.10.0-957.21.3.el7            @updates
    kernel-devel.x86_64                  3.10.0-1160.42.2.el7           @updates
    kernel-devel.x86_64                  3.10.0-1160.45.1.el7           @updates
    kernel-headers.x86_64                3.10.0-1160.45.1.el7           @updates
    kernel-tools.x86_64                  3.10.0-1160.45.1.el7           @updates
    kernel-tools-libs.x86_64             3.10.0-1160.45.1.el7           @updates
    $ cat /etc/redhat-release
    CentOS Linux release 7.9.2009 (Core)
    $
    # yum history package-list kernel.x86_64
​   読み込んだプラグイン:fastestmirror
    ID     | 操作           | Package
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
​       43 | 削除           | kernel-3.10.0-862.3.2.el7.x86_64
​       43 | インストール   | kernel-3.10.0-1160.45.1.el7.x86_64
​       42 | インストール   | kernel-3.10.0-1160.42.2.el7.x86_64                 EE
​       30 | インストール   | kernel-3.10.0-957.21.3.el7.x86_64
​       27 | インストール   | kernel-3.10.0-957.21.2.el7.x86_64
​       14 | 削除           | kernel-3.10.0-514.el7.x86_64
​       14 | 削除           | kernel-3.10.0-693.11.6.el7.x86_64
​       14 | 削除           | kernel-3.10.0-693.17.1.el7.x86_64
​        9 | インストール   | kernel-3.10.0-957.5.1.el7.x86_64                   EE
​        6 | インストール   | kernel-3.10.0-862.3.2.el7.x86_64                   EE
​        5 | インストール   | kernel-3.10.0-693.17.1.el7.x86_64
​        4 | インストール   | kernel-3.10.0-693.11.6.el7.x86_64                  EE
​        1 | インストール   | kernel-3.10.0-514.el7.x86_64
​   history package-list
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

通常の手順 (CentOS なら `yum update`) でインストールされているカーネルであれば、基本的には **累積で過去の修正が含まれている** と考えてよさそうです。

なお、新しいカーネルをインストール後は OS を再起動しないとシステムに反映されません。
`uname -r` コマンドで現在起動しているカーネルバージョンを確認できます。

もしくは、単に古いバージョンのカーネルがインストールされたままになっているため診断ツールに引っ掛かっている可能性もあります。カーネル関連のファイルは `/boot` 領域のディスク容量を圧迫していくので、不要な古いバージョンは整理 (削除) してしまうのも一つの方法です。

CentOS の場合には、`package-cleanup` コマンドに `--oldkernels` オプションを付けて実行することで古いカーネルを削除できます。(デフォルトでは"最新版"と"1つ前"のバージョンを残してそれ以外を削除)

**実行例:**

```
$ sudo package-cleanup --oldkernels
```

**参考:**
[古いカーネルを削除するには - @IT](https://atmarkit.itmedia.co.jp/flinux/rensai/linuxtips/801deloldkernel.html)

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。

お恥ずかしながら、uname -r で確認してみたら、カーネルのバージョンが最新でない事確認できました。
（念のため、last で再起動していない事も確認）

ご指摘いただきました通り、再起動して、uname -rで最新のカーネルである事確認し、
無事、環境Aも環境Bも同じ結果が得られるようになりました。

最新のカーネルバージョンは、基本的には 累積で過去の修正が含まれている事承知しました。

package-cleanup --oldkernels
コマンドについては使ったことがないので、テストできる環境を作って試してみたいと思います。